# How to deny direct access to page

Tags: c#, asp.net, session

how can I deny direct access (by typing the full url) to pages in asp.net, without using roles in web.config something simle.
I've used :

```
if (Session.IsNewSession)
            Response.Redirect("Default.aspx");
```

the problem with it is in the first time everything is ok and the redirect is working, but if I open a new tab in the same browser and enter the url again it fails. 
How can it be solved?
thanx

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

Page 1

```
Context.Items.Add("somevar","someval");
```

Page 2

```
if ( Context.Items["somevar"] == null )
{
    // the page is not redirected from Page 1
}
```

Comment: I would use `Session` instead since that will be persisted between requests. The `Context.Items` collection will be valid for one request alone, so it's not that good of a choice if the OP wants some login logic. If it's a redirect page, then this is a fair solution though.

Answer (score 0):

Using session you can solve this issue.

Build an HttpModule and in context_BeginRequest you can get the current URL . Later conditionally redirect to the default page.

```
public class RedirectionModule : IHttpModule
{
    void context_BeginRequest(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        //this user already already eligible to go inside page ? 
        if (Session["eligible-to-go-inside"] == null)
        {
        //new user
        //check current request url is default.aspx
        //if not forward to  default page
        }

    }
}
```

in default.aspx page if the user full fill the requirement to go to inner page (like logged in) then set

```
Session["eligible-to-go-inside"] = "yes";
```